# Printer Sharing with FreeNAS

Tags: print-server, truenas

I am using [FreeNAS](http://freenas.org/) on my lan to do some file/iTunes sharing but I'd like to add printer sharing to it so that I can stop using a second (aging windows) system.  I'm not familiar with BSDs but I am comfortable with the shell (I'm a Debian admin) are there any good tutorials for setting up printer sharing (cups?) on FreeNAS?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet (will do next week when my NAS box arrives), but [this](http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/freenas/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=1332) forum post explains how to set it up. A couple of other step by step guides: [one](http://www.instructables.com/id/FreeNAS_as_a_Print_Server/) and [two](http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/freenas/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=2116).